# Is an IPv6-Protocol capable of setting route plus source address?

Tags: routing, ipv6, source

This question is related to that question: [Why is Linux choosing the wrong source ip address](https://serverfault.com/q/548448/189616)

Setting a src ip for a static route on client may be okay for one time or if just needed. However in a network of many clients which may even be not under full control this may not be an acceptable workaround. **Is there a standardized protocol which allows to deploy routes together with source addresses to clients automatically?**

For Next-Hop's i know there exists a DHCPv6-option for (Source: https://www.isc.org/blogs/routing-configuration-over-dhcpv6-2/ ) but this seems not to cover the source address.

Answer (score 0):

So as to keep away from confusions when communicating, the host is required to perform both source address choice and source-dependent routing so the suitable next packet is chosen while considering the source address to dodge the need of changing the source IPv6 prefix.

IPv6 uses source steering system to keep away from huge directing tables on memory-obliged switches.

Stateless Address Auto-configuration (SLAAC) convention causes customers to dole out IP address themselves without depending on a DHCPv6 server.

Comment: Maybe unterstanding the "source steering system" is my problem. Do you have some sources which may help? As in linked question a wrong source was selected - i want to understand how a selection is done when a more specific route does not seem to have any influence.

Comment: Here you will have some basic understanding about address selection.
http://biplane.com.au/blog/?p=22